# MySQL one table inner join with 3 different entity tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I got 4 tables, **Email_Company_Contact_Ref** table is the table which linked with Email, Company, and Contact.

```
**Email_Company_Contact_Ref**

id = primary key
email_id = reference to Email.`id`
ref_id = it can be Company.id / Contact.id
table = reference from which table name
```

[image: table structure]

I try to use left join to get my output, but I got duplicated result. If I try inner join, I will not get any result at all, it is because Company and Contact this two tables does not have any thing common.

This is the output I would like to complete.

[image: output result]

I able to use UNION to get the output, but it not really effective. I am thinking it should be a way to get the output result.. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: How `Company` and `Contact` tables are linked to `Email_Company_Contact_Ref` table? Please show your query with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Is it standard to have a database schema like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my mysql answer, hope this can help

```
SELECT e.email, r.table, c1.name AS company_name, c2.name AS contact_name
FROM email_company_contact_ref r
JOIN email e ON e.id = r.email_id
LEFT JOIN company c1 ON (c1.id = r.ref_id AND r.table = 'company')
LEFT JOIN contact c2 ON (c2.id = r.ref_id AND r.table = 'contact')
GROUP BY r.table, e.email
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done without a UNION. Here's my suggestion.

```
SELECT email_address, eccr.table table, company_name, contact_name
FROM Email e, Email_Company_Contact_Ref eccr,
     (SELECT "Company" table, id, company_name, NULL contact_name
      FROM Company
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "Contact" table, id, NULL company_name, contact_name
      FROM Contact) cc
WHERE e.id = eccr.email_id
AND eccr.table = cc.table
AND eccr.email_id = cc.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the `ref_id` part... Is it a foreign key? Or is that the primary key for the `Email_Company_Contact_Ref` table?

I would think you'd want to put the reference for the `Email` table in the `Company` and `Contact` tables. If you need more than one emails for them, then you should create *two* join tables: `Company_Email` and `Contact_Email`. Your current design (with references to table names as values for a column) is bad SQL design -- just because things like RoR promote it, it won't get any better.

With proper design, the equivalent of that complicated query would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Company_Email (company_id integer, email_address varchar(100),
  FOREIGN KEY company_id REFERENCES Company (id));

CREATE TABLE Contact_Email (contact_id integer, email_address varchar(100),
  FOREIGN KEY contact_id REFERENCES Contact (id));

SELECT email_address, 'Company' AS kind, company_name AS name
  FROM Company_Email ce JOIN Company c ON company_id = c.id
 UNION
SELECT email_address, 'Contact', contact_name
  FROM Contact_Email ce JOIN Contact c ON contact_id = c.id;
```

If you can't change it, you'll have to do the UNION along the lines Barmar explained it.

Or, you can do a `SELECT DISTINCT` to get rid of the duplicates from your left joined query.

Comment: Hi dakhota, thank you for your suggestion. This database structure is not able to change it, it is up and running system. I cannot do anything for the table structure.